# Update query: Sum divided by Count between 2 different columns in 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to be able to sum the financial data from a column on one table (containing both negative and positive values) and divide that equally by the total number of accounts in another table.

I tried several variations on nesting my SELECT statements, but that must not be the issue as I continue to get the message "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

'Cost' is a blank column simply to insert the values.  It's a decimal(18,2) type. 
The 'Financial' and 'Types' tables each have an acct # that I use to join the data; the 'Master' table has unrelated account numbers and doesn't share any unifying data with the financial and type tables.

```
UPDATE MasterTable
Set Cost =
(SELECT SUM(FinancialTable.Jan)
FROM FinancialTable
LEFT JOIN TypesTable
ON FinancialTable.Acct2 = TypesTable.Acct2)
WHERE (TypesTable.Type = 'overhead')
AND (FinancialTable.Unit = 123))

/

(SELECT COUNT(MasterTable.Acct1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code in the question. Firstly it has one too many closing brackets. Secondly,

```
select count(MasterTable.Acct1)
```

is not a valid query in and of itself. If it was, the code would be free of syntax issues.

If you want to aggregate with an update statement, then you have to use subqueries and do the aggregation in them. So you were almost there. I would also change the left join to an inner join for readability - as it is effectively an inner join as you are referencing one of the fields of TypesTable in your where clause.

All of this gives rise to **this [SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10a60/2)** I have set up for you.

Finally though - I don't think the fixed code I have made does what you want it to. 
It is setting the Cost field for every field in MasterTable - is that what really what you want to do? I suspect you want to join onto it perhaps with the Acct1 field? If you can clarify your question you might get the answer you really want.

Comment: I think this does what I want - basically if I have a sum total of $100 in overhead costs and 10 customer accounts in the master table, then I want the cost column to say $10 for each customer account in the master table.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by what the error says try declaring a variable and placing that in the Set command. It appears you cannot use a query inside an Update statement

```
 Declare @count as int
 Set @count = (Select COUNT(MasterTable.Acct1))

 Declare @sum as int 
 Set @sum = (SELECT SUM(FinancialTable.Jan)
        FROM FinancialTable
        LEFT JOIN TypesTable
        ON FinancialTable.Acct2 = TypesTable.Acct2
        WHERE (TypesTable.Type = 'overhead')
        AND (FinancialTable.Unit = 123))       

 Declare @cost as int
 Set @cost = @sum / @count

 Update MasterTable
 Set Cost = @cost
```